# Ligature problem with xelatex and Gillius ADF

Tags: xetex, ligatures

I have a strange problem when using xelatex and Gillius ADF.
Whenever I type `oe` it gets parsed to the Œ ligature.

Here's a very minimal example:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{Gillius ADF}
\begin{document}
    \begin{frame}
        does
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

And this is the output:

[image: MWE]

Any idea how I can turn this off?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turn of the “Required” ligatures:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\setsansfont{Gillius ADF}[Ligatures=NoRequired]

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}

does firefly fluffier ae

\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]